# Android AlertDialog Multi Choice Items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I have an activity for user with a button called choose days 
when user clicks the button it show a alert dialog for selecting the day of week

now i want when user select multiple days

then previously selected check box will show in check position and remains with uncheck position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) is a nice library for that, I use it for my project.
[image]

Step 1:

Add these lines to your build.gradle file

```
  dependencies {
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.7.0'
}

repositories 
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }
}
```

Step 2:
In code where you want to show dialog add this:

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
    .title(R.string.title)
    .items(R.array.items)
    .itemsCallbackMultiChoice(null, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackMultiChoice() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, Integer[] which, CharSequence[] text) {
            /**
             * If you use alwaysCallMultiChoiceCallback(), which is discussed below,
             * returning false here won't allow the newly selected check box to actually be selected.
             * See the limited multi choice dialog example in the sample project for details.
             **/
             return true;
        }
    })
    .positiveText(R.string.choose)
    .show();
```

**items(R.array.items)** - that should be an array of string values in your resources.

P.S. Please read the documentation of this library, it very clear and simply)

[image]

Comment: i don't understand ...? how to use that library

Comment: @SinkuPaliwal, you must add the [dependency](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#gradle-dependency-jcenter) in build.gradle, then implement [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#multi-choice-list-dialogs) and it all)

Comment: from where i can  get some code denis pls send complete url

Comment: @SinkuPaliwal, click on the link above the picture, from there. In my third comment I put 2 direct links

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at the Android standard. [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

It also shows you how to create a custom dialog. They have an example of a list with checkboxes

Comment: Go to the link and then scroll down. there is a example of a custom dialog. you can change te login dialog view to your own layout. I'm not going to post code here, that is not good for the readability.

Comment: Take a look at this code in the example: 

`LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))`

Comment: @R. Adang: Your link to Dialogs shows Page Not Found error. Please update.